# Fastest way to store and obtain data in PHP

Tags: php, database, performance

We are making a web frontend for a smart LED strip interface.

The part where I am now is making a functionality where two LED strips in different homes can be linked together (not the same local area network). This is done using one server and multiple clients.

This is done using Apache. The server is basically a REST API where you can POST (for setting) and GET (for obtaining) the hexadecimal color code. All updateable data on the API is no more than 1KB. 
How it is currently designed, 5 requests per second per client are made to the server. This is by design.

All works well, and I have zero performance issues. 
However, I want the obtaining of the color code to be as swift as possible. My question is: 
What is the fastest way to store and obtain such small data in PHP?

I have looked into different solutions, for example databases, storing it raw in a file using `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents`, storing it in environment variables, but I found no documentation on performance.

Comment: Its not clear how big the data set is that you are getting this value from

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated my question. The question is only about the color code problem though, so that will be around 6 bytes

Comment: So you always pass the same value back to the caller

Comment: @RiggsFolly sounds like the POST sets the value and the GET reads the same value every 200ms to check for changes.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, when there is a POST request made to the API saying that the value should be set to e.g. FF0000 it should return FF0000 once a GET request is made indicating the value should be obtained and returned

Comment: @Andrew exactly

Comment: Sounds like a cache would be a good solution

Comment: I agree with the cache - using any of your other methods as a backup incase the server goes down and the cache clears - just try to load into the cache from that on start - file may be the best choice for that, database would be excessive to store 5 bytes.

Comment: a rest call is much slower than using a websocket and fgc is about 50% slower than using curl, also you can trim bytes off by just using a number from 0 to 255 vs a hex, if your sending it 5 times a second

Comment: +1 for websocket. Using REST calls to retrieve literally 3 bytes of information means that every call is going to be 99%+ overhead. Then at that point you can just push updates from the server side and remove the polling entirely.